# How can I align one content div to the middle and another to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have these divs, how could I go about aligning `.Div1` in the middle and `.Div2` in the bottom?

```css
.Div1 {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 90px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 25%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="Div1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; color: rgb(255, 255, 
                  255); border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 30px;  position: relative">
  I-BS
  <div class="Div2">
    <p>
      <FONT size=auto>
        <STRONG>A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D</STRONG>
      </FONT>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.

This snippet demonstrates a couple of CSS features, using CSS flex to align the content of Div1 centrally and positioning Div2 relatively at the bottom of its parent.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .Div1 {
      background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      line-height: 90px;
      background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 25%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
      /* ADDED */
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .Div2 {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <head>

    <body>
      <div class="Div1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; color: rgb(255, 255, 
                  255); border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 30px;  position: relative">
        I-BS
        <div class="Div2">
          <p>
            <FONT size=auto>
              <STRONG>A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D</STRONG>
            </FONT>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**Notes for this demo:**

`body` has been used as the containing element from which Div1 can take its dimensions. And `body` has been given the viewport width and height.

The default margins added by browsers have been removed from elements just to demonstrate getting full viewport/screen coverage.

**Further notes:**

You may like to put your code through a validator just to ensure it is uptodate.

For example, the `font` tag is deprecated in HTML5 - switching to CSS is recommended.

The `border-collapse` property is probably not helping here as it refers to a `table` element.

It depends on exactly what you want for the spacing of the characters in Div2, but it may be that using CSS `flex` could help here if for example you'd like the ABCD to be spaced evenly along the bottom. See e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)